# Cocoa/AppleScript - Downloading a file from a website with a progress bar - Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript

I am creating a launcher/updater for my Unity game, and I'm using a Cocoa/AppleScript type project so I can download updates from my web server and launch them, but I have no idea how to do that, I would also like to implement a progress bar that shows people the progress of the download/update.

The OS is OSX 10.10 (Yosemite)

Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: Somehow I have the feeling you shouldn't reinvent the wheel - isn't there some update "thing" in Unity itself? I don't know Unity but if you can use Objective-C  Code/Frameworks I would suggest to try Sparkle ( http://sparkle-project.org ) -

Comment: @Zero Unfortunately there is no update "thing" in Unity. I wanted to have a nice custom updater and launcher, kind of like the SimCity Origin Launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an app update, if it is not in App Store, the option that you have is Sparkle (http://sparkle-project.org/). if it is a single app, you will be able to use sparkle directly. If your product is a complex one with installer (pkg etc), you can tweak sparkle a bit to support that.